# RegExp character class with RegExp constructor JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am building a simple RegExp helper for my own personal use.  Essentially, it's going to work with method chaining and return the string with all of the selected elements.

The question I have is how to use a character class with the `RegExp` constructor.  Here is my code:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(this.expression.join(''), "g");
```

As you can see, I am passing my expression in the first argument and a flag in the second.

My question is, how can I use the `RegExp` constructor and wrap it in a character class, like `/[...]/`?

Answer (score 1):

The `RegExp` constructor takes a string, so you can do string things with it:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("["+this.expression.join('')+"]","g");
```

Comment: Ahh, word.  Is there no parameter for this in the constructor?